# UITextView doesn't update text after segue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I'm trying to update a UITextView's text property, after a segue, which happens after a row of a table view is tapped.

here is my code

MasterViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"4 Choices"]) {
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue is called");
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *questionContent = [[selectedObject valueForKey:@"questionContent"]description];
    self.questionContent = questionContent;
    [segue.destinationViewController setTextViewWith:self.questionContent];
}
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called");
NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSNumber *questionID = [selectedObject valueForKey:@"qID"];
int i = [questionID intValue];
if (i == 1) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"4 Choices" sender:self];
}
else
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"5 Choices" sender:self];
}
}
```

DetailViewController.m

```
-(void)setTextViewWith:(NSString *)aText
{
self.questionText = aText;
NSLog(@"setTextViewWith is called");

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self.questionView setText:self.questionText];
NSLog(@"viewWillAppear is called");
}
```

EDIT 1 : change the code to set the text at 'viewWillAppear'
EDIT 2 : add 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath'

Note : the segue was pointed from MasterViewController to DetailViewController (not from the 
tableViewCell)

Thanks for your help : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text view may not be loaded at the prepareForSegue point. I've only just started with storyboards and have found that I had to set string properties on the destination view controller instead, then update the UI components in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.

Comment: I tried setting the text in 'viewWillAppear', but it wouldn't work.

Comment: After creating a new string property on the destination view controller as I suggested? You set the string in prepareForSegue, then in viewWillAppear set the textfield text to the string.

Comment: I've already set the string property in destinationViewController. I will edit the post in a minute.

Comment: Are all those log messages coming out?

Comment: Yes, all the methods were called. I will update 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' for your information.

Comment: You should include the string value in each of the log messages, so you can see if it is being lost anywhere.

Comment: All the strings oddly turned out to be nil. I had checked that before but they were fine. And the weird thing is that the label of the tableView is still there; and it is being pulled from the same attribute of the same entity.